# Titling package gives "Undefined control sequence" error when using a macro that defines a dimen in the title

Tags: dimensions, titling

I have a macro that defines a new dimension (details have been stripped away for the MWE; in the actual command, I want to store an old value in the new one so I can modify it temporarily and then restore the old value, so defining it outside the command won't work). I can run this command in the title just fine---unless I load the `titling` package, in which case I get an undefined control sequence error for `\x`, even if I don't call `\maketitle` in the document. Is there a way to resolve this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titling} % Comment this out and it works

\newcommand{\test}{%
    \newdimen\x \x=1pt
}

\title{\test}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you more `\newdimen\x` out of the `\newcommand`, the error is gone. Do you need it inside the command?

Comment: To expand on the comment by @Schrödinger'scat, it's inadvisable to use `\newdimen` in a command that will be called more than once.  Instead, create `\newdimen` independently, then set it inside the "active" command definition.